# Textarea and checkbox cause submit button to fail in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php upload button with an onclick event.  Until very recently it worked in Firefox 67, but it does not change on hover and it is no longer clickable.  But the same button works with no problem in  Chrome.

I isolated the problem to two form elements:  textarea and checkbox.  When I insert either of them above the submit button, it no longer works (the cursor does not change and the button no longer submits) .  I tested this button with php about two weeks ago and it worked perfectly.  Now it no longer works.

Here is the entire page code:

```
<div class="center_text_grid flex-item joinpage_text">Introductory sign-up page text goes here.<br></div><br><br>

<!-- ________________ -->

<form action="register.php" method="post" name='register' id='register'>

    <div><input type="hidden" id="datefield" name="datefield" value="Today"></div>

    <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;">
    <input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:80%; font-size: 18px;" required></div>

    <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;"><input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus placeholder="First Name (optional)" id="firstname" name="firstname" style="width:80%;"></div>

    <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;">
    <input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus placeholder="Last Name (optional)" id="lastname" name="lastname" style="width:80%;"></div><br>

<!-- THE SUBMIT BUTTON WORKS HERE WITH EVERYTHING BELOW COMMENTED OUT -->

    <textarea maxlength="1000" id="comments" name="comments" cols="3" rows="3" autofocus placeholder="Comments"></textarea><br>

<label class="container">
   <span class="joinpage_checkbox">Add me to your email list</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx" checked="checked" value="Yes">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<!-- THE SUBMIT BUTTON STOPS WORKING HERE WITH EITHER OR BOTH OF TEXTAREA AND CHECKBOX -->

<div class="center_text_grid flex-item EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:27%;"><button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit" onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx(); CollectData();">Click here to sign up</button></div>

<!--CollectData();-->

<script>
function GetDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + month + '/' + day;
    console.log(output);
    document.getElementById("datefield").value = output; }
</script>

<script>
function GetCkBx() {
    var ckbxYN = $("#ckbx").is(':checked');
     document.getElementById("checkbox").value = ckbxYN; }
</script>

<script>
function CollectData() {
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
}
</script>

</form><br>

<br><br><br>
```

So the problem is with either or both of these:

```
    <textarea maxlength="1000" id="comments" name="comments" cols="3" rows="3" autofocus placeholder="Comments"></textarea><br>

<label class="container">
   <span class="joinpage_checkbox">Add me to your email list</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx" checked="checked" value="Yes">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Two big mysteries are why did it work until recently and why does it work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Thanks for any help on this.

EDIT:

In reply to request below, here is register.php with dummy values for sensitive information:

```
<?php
// PHP file upload using PDO
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);

$params = [
    'host' => '000.000.000.000',
    'port' => '5432',
    'user' => 'username',
    'pwd' => 'password',
    'db' => 'dbname' ];

try {
$pdo->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO psq01 ('"
. implode("','", $fields) . "') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $row) $stmt->execute($row);
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    $pdo->rollBack();
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for this line: `document.getElementById("checkbox").value = ckbxYN;` (which doesn't make sense anyway, since you're grabbing the value in the previous line, and trying to assign it back to the checkbock but used `checkbox` as id instead of `ckbx`)

Comment: The next error is about `ShowAjax` not being defined, a function you're calling in the button's `onclick` but I don't see anywhere in the code you've posted. When I remove the call, the form gets sent, twice. Once per AJAX and once by the browser, since you aren't stopping the submit event.

Comment: Chris, ShowAjax merely shows another page after the button is clicked and the data submitted.  It's long but I'll edit to post it if you need it.  I have tested this page before and the scripts all work to submit, but very recently the click button has stopped functioning as a button, due to the two html elements I showed above.

Comment: With regard to your first comment above, did you get the submit button to work as it is now.  I can't even get that far.

Comment: @PeterSmith Can you attach register.php to this page?

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/d2ekocL5/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @Chis G - I'll work on that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error in the updated code is in the `GetCkBx` function at

`document.getElementById("checkbox").value = ckbxYN; }`

You target an invalid html ID, you should target `ckbx`.

> **Tip:** By default, an unchecked checkbox will not reach the request, to make this happen, create an input with type hidden and the same name as the checkbox, to fake a default value for the checkbox.
>
> As such, if the checkbox is unchecked, then the hidden field will be sent.
>
> Change from this:
>
> `<input type="checkbox" id="ckbx" checked="checked" value="Yes">`
>
> To this:
>
> `<input type="hidden" name="my_custom_checkbox" value="No">`
>
> `<input type="checkbox" id="ckbx" name="my_custom_checkbox" checked="checked" value="Yes">`

See the bellow code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center_text_grid flex-item joinpage_text">Introductory sign-up page text goes here.<br></div><br><br>

<!-- ________________ -->

<form action="register.php" method="post" name='register' id='register'>

  <div><input type="hidden" id="datefield" name="datefield" value="Today"></div>

  <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;">
    <input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:80%; font-size: 18px;" required></div>

  <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;"><input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus placeholder="First Name (optional)" id="firstname" name="firstname" style="width:80%;"></div>

  <div class="center_text_grid flex-item mktg_text EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:12.5%;">
    <input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus placeholder="Last Name (optional)" id="lastname" name="lastname" style="width:80%;"></div><br>

  <!-- THE SUBMIT BUTTON WORKS HERE WITH EVERYTHING BELOW COMMENTED OUT -->

  <textarea maxlength="1000" id="comments" name="comments" cols="3" rows="3" autofocus placeholder="Comments"></textarea><br>

  <label class="container">
   <span class="joinpage_checkbox">Add me to your email list</span>
  <input type="hidden" name="my_custom_checkbox" value="No">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx" name="my_custom_checkbox" checked="checked" value="Yes">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

  <!-- THE SUBMIT BUTTON STOPS WORKING HERE WITH EITHER OR BOTH OF TEXTAREA AND CHECKBOX -->

  <div class="center_text_grid flex-item EMail_Pwd" style="padding-left:27%;"><button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit" onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx(); CollectData();  ;">Click here to sign up</button></div>

  <!--CollectData();-->

  <script>
    function GetDate() {
      var d = new Date();
      var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
      var day = d.getDate();
      var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' + month + '/' + day;
      console.log(output);
      document.getElementById("datefield").value = output;
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function GetCkBx() {
      var ckbxYN = $("#ckbx").is(':checked');
      document.getElementById("ckbx").value = ckbxYN;
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function CollectData() {
      form_data = $('form').serialize()
      return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(responseText) {},
        error: function(error) {
          console.log("Okay, I failed" + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

</form><br>

<br><br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will test this out now and post back about the results.  Meanwhile, the textarea box without the checkbox has the same problem.  Any insights into why the textarea box causes the same problem?

Comment: I would consider refactoring that `JavaScript` code since you use `jQuery`, you don't need to mess the HTML code with inline JavaScript. And you don't need 3 `<script>` tags, one is enough, just put your JS code in it.

Comment: Your code does work without the textarea.  As a matter of form the JS code should be in files; I put it inline with the html for convenience.  Thank again for your help.